# wired and wireless do not work: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled

Tags: 12.04, wireless, internet

My WIFI or wired internet will not work. And there are these 2 error codes.

```
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled /
iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
```

I am running 12.04 LTS. How do i fix this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the wifi module loaded, iwl is an intel driver. I'm not sure what make you have, but some manufacturers windows version works better with the ndiswrapper installed.

Comment: I believe those are information messages, not errors. What does this tell us? rfkill list all also: dmesg | grep iwl